# jQuery.POST - pass another parameter with Form.Serialize() - Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

As I am working on Asp.Net MVC Application, in my application I am using `jQuery.POST` method to submit a form.

e.g.

```
jQuery.post('/Product/Save', jQuery(document.forms[0]).serialize(), 
       function (data) { alert('Product Added Successfully.); }
);
```

In above code snippet, I want to pass another parameter.. let's say.. `ProductID`.

So, the idea is, I want to pass both `jQuery(document.forms[0]).serialize()` and `ProductID variable` in `jQuery.POST method`, so I can get both `Form and ProductID` in my `controller's action method`.

Could anybody please let me know that I would I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [following plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery) to serialize the form into a JSON object and add another parameters:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

like this:

```
var data = $('form').serializeObject();
data['ProductId'] = '123';
$.post('<%= Url.Action("Save", "Product") %>', data, function (data) { 
    alert('Product Added Successfully.'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Url.Action method to build your calling URL? You can include the additional data you need that way.

```
<%: Url.Action('Save', 'Product', new { "ProductID", your product id }) %>
```

This would replace the hard-coded URL in your jQuery.post method call.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 var url = '<%= Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<MyController>(c => c.Save(":productId")) %>';
```

You could later replace the url with the actual value in your post URL.

```
 url.replace(':productId', $productId);
```